# Enable client to create his own forms

Tags: php, ajax, automation

I have a client that has a contact page and he wants to be able to create and edit the contact form fields.
Is there a simple php class for this?

I don't really know where to start with this.

Any tips?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use client side language as like JQuery for this

Comment: You first learn html,css,javascript,Jquery in the same order.You can start with [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tutorialslibrary.htm)

Comment: I know jquery php and all that, I'm just asking what the best way/easiest would be to do this properly.

Answer (score 0):

### This custom Jquery Code show how you can done your job by using Jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
  $("#add").on('click', function() {
    $('#extra').css('display', 'block');
  });
  
  $('#dy_add').click(function(){
    var type = $("#type").val();
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var inputName = $("#m_nam").val();
  
    var form_field = inputName + '<input type="'+type +'" name="'+name+'" />' +'</br>' ;
    
    $("#dynamic").append(form_field);
  });
});
```

```css
#extra{display:none}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST" >
 First Name <input type="text" name="fname" /></br>
 Last Name <input type="text" name="lname" /></br>
 <div id="dynamic"></div>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<button id="add">Add Fields</button>
<div id="extra">
<p><font color="red">Add extra form field</font></p>
Name<input type="text" id="m_nam" placeholder="input type"></br>
Type<input type="text" id="type" placeholder="input type"></br>
Input Name<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="input name">
<button id="dy_add">Add</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```